# animating multiple markers in OpenLayers 3

Tags: animation, openlayers-3

I am creating animations of migrating sea animals across the Pacific using OpenLayers. I would like each "animal" to trace a track as it goes over time. At the head of the track will be an icon/marker/overlay representing that animal. I have gotten this to work for one track, but although I am able to grow the track of each animal as a linestring constructed segment by segment, I am unable to specifically assign an icon/marker/overlay to each track. Instead, I am only able to animate one icon on one track. The rest of the linestring tracks proceed, but they do not have an icon at the head of the track as it is traced out. Here is my code. Any help appreciated.

```
    // draw tracks

    function makeLineString(id, species, multipointCoords, tracksTime) {

        // layer structure and style assignment

        var trackSource = new ol.source.Vector();

        var trackLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: trackSource,
            style: BWtrackStyle
        });
        map.addLayer(trackLayer);

        var lineString = new ol.geom.LineString([
            ol.proj.fromLonLat(multipointCoords[0][0])
        ]);

        var trackFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: lineString
        });

        if (species === "Blue Whale") {
            trackFeature.setStyle([BWtrackStyle, shadowStyle]);
        };

        trackSource.addFeature(trackFeature);

        // icon-marker-overlay styling

        var BW2205005icon = document.getElementById('BW2205005icon');
        var BW2205005marker = new ol.Overlay({
            positioning: 'center-center',
            offset: [0, 0],
            element: BW2205005icon,
            stopEvent: false
        });
        map.addOverlay(BW2205005marker);

        var BW2205012icon = document.getElementById('BW2205012icon');
        var BW2205012marker = new ol.Overlay({
            positioning: 'center-center',
            offset: [0, 0],
            element: BW2205012icon,
            stopEvent: false
        });
        map.addOverlay(BW2205012marker);

        var coordinate, i = 1,
            length = multipointCoords[0].length;

        var currentTime = tracksTime[0][0];
        var nextTime = tracksTime[0][1];
        speedOption = 100; // the highter this value, the faster the tracks, see next line
        var transitionTime = (nextTime - currentTime) / speedOption;
        console.log(transitionTime);

        var timer;

        timer = setInterval(function() {
            segmentConstruction(id, multipointCoords, tracksTime);
        }, transitionTime);

        function segmentConstruction(id, multipointCoords, tracksTime) {
            coordinate = ol.proj.fromLonLat(multipointCoords[0][i]);
            lineString.appendCoordinate(coordinate);
            console.log(id);

            if (id === "BW2205005") {
                BW2205005marker.setPosition(coordinate);
            } else {

                BW2205012marker.setPosition(coordinate);
            };

            if (i >= length - 1) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            } else {
                i++;
                clearInterval(timer);
                currentTime = tracksTime[0][i];
                nextTime = tracksTime[0][i + 1];
                transitionTime = (nextTime - currentTime) / speedOption;
                timer = setInterval(function() {
                    segmentConstruction(id, multipointCoords, tracksTime);
                }, transitionTime);
            };
        };
    };
```

Comment: I should add that this code was inspired by this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/2VNqoz?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your overlay is being reused for each line.  In any case, it would probably be simpler and more performant to use a point feature instead of the overlay, as follows:

- add a new style to your layer for points (circle, image, etc.)
- add a point feature representing the head of each line
- update the coordinates of the point feature when necessary

In other words, each animal would have a linestring and a point feature.  The style on the layer would include the stroke style for the line and the icon style for the point.

You could also style the points independently by giving each point feature it's own style, or using a style function on the layer.

Comment: What do you mean by: "I think your overlay is being reused for each line" ? Thanks.

Comment: Most examples do use a div overlay and animate it using .setPosition. To do it with a point feature, I suppose one would use .setGeometry or perhaps the experimental vectorContext?

Comment: I'm assuming you have many linestrings, but it looks like you only have two overlays, so when you change the coordinates to match the end of a linestring, it would move an existing overlay.  That may explain why you are not seeing expected behavior.

Comment: Though vectorContext seems to need an event to trigger it.

Comment: Yes, to use a point feature you would update the point's coordinates with setCoordinates().

Comment: The vectorContext could be used to do true animation via the postcompose event.

Comment: Great advice. I got it working. Thank you for getting me out of the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this for animation of multiple markers with smooth movement, but it requires a delay for other styles:

```
      var vehicles= [{ "curlon":77.654397, "curlat":12.959898, "prevlon":77.651951, "prevlat":12.951074 },{ "curlon":77.672936, "curlat":12.958100, "prevlon":77.649290, "prevlat":12.960024 }];

            function push_data_for_multimarker(map,gps_obj)
            {
             destruct=false;
               var getz = gps_obj;
               var data_arry = [];
               for (var i = 0, length = getz.length; i < length; i++)
               {
                gps_smooth_coordinates_generator(parseFloat(getz[i].prevlon),parseFloat(getz[i].prevlat),parseFloat(getz[i].curlon),parseFloat(getz[i].curlat));
               }
            }


            function gps_smooth_coordinates_generator(map,sourcelon,sourcelat,destinationlon,destinationlat)
            {
                var vehicle_data=[];

                var beginz=ol.proj.transform([sourcelon,sourcelat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

                var endz=ol.proj.transform([destinationlon,destinationlat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');


                vehicle_data.push(beginz);
                vehicle_data.push(endz);
                var path= vehicle_data;
                var genrated_positions = [];
                          for(var k = 1;k<path.length;k++)
                              {
                                  var pointsNo = 1000;
                                  var startPos = {};
                                  startPos.lat = path[k-1][1];
                                  startPos.lng = path[k-1][0];
                                  var endPos = {};
                                  endPos.lat = path[k][1];
                                  endPos.lng = path[k][0];
                                  var latDelta = (endPos.lat - startPos.lat) / pointsNo;
                                  var lngDelta = (endPos.lng - startPos.lng) / pointsNo;

                                  for (var i = 0; i < pointsNo; i++) 
                                  {
                                      var curLat = startPos.lat + i * latDelta;
                                      var curLng = startPos.lng + i * lngDelta;
                                      var arr = [];
                                      arr.push(curLng);
                                      arr.push(curLat);
                                      genrated_positions.push(arr);
                                  }
                              }

                           animate_multiple_marker(genrated_positions);
            }

    function animate_multiple_marker(map,veh_croods)
      {
        var routeCoords = veh_croods;
        var routeLength = routeCoords.length;
        console.log("routeCoords"+routeCoords);
        console.log("routeLength"+routeLength);
        var geoMarker = new ol.Feature({
        type: 'geoMarker',
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords[0])
      });


      var off_style =new ol.style.Style({
          image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 7,
            snapToPixel: false,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'black'}),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: 'white', width: 2
            })
          })
        });

            var now;
            var animating = false;
            var speed=20;

            var moveFeature = function(event) {
            var vectorContext = event.vectorContext;
            var frameState = event.frameState;

            if (animating) {
              var elapsedTime = frameState.time - now;
              var index = Math.round(speed * elapsedTime / 1000);
              if (index >= routeLength) {
                console.log("index>>"+index);
                stopAnimation();
                animating = false;
                console.log("animation ends");
              }
              if(animating)
                    {
                          var currentPoint = new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords[index]);
                          var feature = new ol.Feature(currentPoint);
                          vectorContext.drawFeature(feature,off_style);

                    }
              else
              {}

              if(destruct)
                {
                  console.log("termination initiated");
                  stopAnimation();            
                  //destruct=false;
                }
                else
                { }
            }
            else
            {
              console.log("Not amnimating!!");
            }
            // tell OL3 to continue the postcompose animation
            map.render();
          };

            triggerz_animation();


        function stopAnimation() {
        animating = false;
        caller=false;
        //remove listener
          map.un('postcompose', moveFeature);
        }

          function start_vehicles()
          {
          animating = true;
          now = new Date().getTime();
          map.on('postcompose', moveFeature);
          map.render();
          }


            if(caller)
            {

              start_vehicles();

            }
            else
            {


            }
      }

      var caller=false;
      var drive_vehicle;

      function triggerz_animation()
      {
        caller=true;
      }
      var destruct=false;
      function collapse_animation()
      {
        destruct=true;
      }
```

with reference to 
http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html?q=animation

Let this be helpfull..Thank You
pass data as json to the function: 
push_data_for_multimarker(map,vehicles);